# Is there a way to save remote urls as they are with CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Is there a way to configure CarrierWave to not download remote images but save the urls as they are?

This is probably a strange question, but there is a case that we do not care the real size of the image if it comes from somewhere outside our website.

**Update:**

Why not just use a string field to store the url?

Because not all images come from remote urls, some of them are uploaded by users.

I'm just curious if there is a way to configure CarrierWave like that.

Comment: It's very dangerous to save only url because if this is removed, you're DB is corrupted.. If you really want to store only the url, you don't need CarrierWave to do it. Just make a condition before creating your photo. If it's uploaded by users then you create the photo through CarrierWave. Else you juste save the given url.

Answer (score 0):

Why use carrierwave so? Just use a string field to store the url.

Comment: Some images come from remote urls but some are uploaded by users.